# Why is there no "the" before the word "war" in this phrase: at the outbreak of war?

Tags: articles

Is it a grammatical rule which means there is a list of "you shouldn't use an article here", or is it just a pattern of "the outbreak of something"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a solid reference/rule on when not to put article after 'of'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313276/is-there-a-solid-reference-rule-on-when-not-to-put-article-after-of) In particular, "war" is a mass noun here (compare "the outbreak of the war" which refers to a specific war, possibly by contrast with another war, rather than the outbreak of fighting).

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I want to ask. And unfortunately, there seems to be no accepted answer in that post.

Answer (score 0):

"At the outbreak of war..."  i think in this context, 'war' is an activity that people may be involved with.
"At the outbreak of the war..."  refers to a particular or specific period of conflict.

In a conversation, when using the first phrase, the phrase will probably be being used in a context where it is understood WHICH period of conflict was being referred to.